# Can i exploit TecDoc database, and how?

Tags: c#

I need to query the TECDOC database from my app, is there a relation database manager behind or a specific works by the provider, can i convert it?

Comment: No idea in C#, but you can try to use phantomjs to construct your own database. Of course, it won't be easy if you don't know javascript, or parsing mechanisms. http://phantomjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

There is a web service you can use

https://www.tecalliance.net/en/products/tecdoc-catalogue-web-service/

Comment: I need an offline solution?

Comment: If you just direct it at the IP adress "Localhost", you got a "offline solution". Just because you run a Server does not mean it has to run on another computer too.

Comment: @Christopher, how to connect to local host, i see all peoples talking about mysql in case of TecDoc, i don't found any trace of mysql installed with!, is there any idea?

Comment: too exensive , tecdoc web service costs up to 50 k Euro, for a startup it will be not easy to buy,

Comment: TecDoc Database is up to 80GB big. Good luck integrating into an "offline app"